# C++ ,pointers and operators

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to take only the even array indexes number (including 0)(array that user enters) and make its new array with only those elements and not the odd ones::: C++
my code: 
 n= no. of elements user enters
a is an array of user entered no.s

```
for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++){                  
  arr[i] = *(a+2i);
}
```

the error:

> error: invalid operands of types 'int*' and '**complex** int' to binary 'operator+'

```
arr[i] = *(a+2i);
```

how to fix and what does it mean?

Comment: If you want to multiply 2 with i, you have to write 2*i not 2i

Comment: `a + 2i` is indeed a [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), and in C++14 [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) was introduced for it. C++ does not have implicit multiplication like in math.

Comment: On an unrelated note, for any pointer `p` and index `i` the expression `*(p + i)` is equal to `p[i]`. That is, in your case you could save a couple of key-presses by writing `a[2 * i]` instead of `*(a + 2 * i)`.

Comment: Use square brackets to access arrays: `array[index]`. While `*(array+index)` syntax is equally valid for technical reasons, is not supposed to be used. Better yet, don't use plain C-style arrays at all. Between std::vector and std::array, there's no reason to.

Comment: @n.m. There's technical reasons other than it looks awful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*(a+2i);
```

is invalid (and looks like a imaginary number of the form `a+jb`) that is the meaning of the error.

You mean for sure `*(a + 2*i);` because the compiler can

not associate the mat operation if the mat operator is missing and is instead interpreting that as an imaginary number.

This is because `2i` is not automatically inferred as `2*i`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use pointer arithmetic to get the result you want.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (n / 2); ++i) 
{
     arr[i] = a[2 * i];
}
```

Comment: It's still pointer arithmetic involved, it just happens behind the scene by the compiler. And this doesn't really answer the question.